# Как проще всего реализовать такой input с выпадающим списком языков?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: 1]

[image: 2]
У списка обратите внимание на стрелку

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не могу писать комментарии из-за ниского рейтинга напишу сюда теоретически как это сделать:

```html
<label>Введите номер вашего телефона</label>    
<input type="text" placeholder="+7 ___-__-__">
<select><option value=""><img src=".svg"></option><option value="2"><img src=".svg"></option> и тд.</select>
```

Далее создаете CSS класс содержащий:

```
    display: flex;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
```

Оборачиваете все в DIV что бы вышло:

```css
.dflex1 {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.bl1 {
margin-top: 30px;
}
.bl2 {
position: absolute;
background: white;
top: 20px;
left:30px
}
.bl3 {
width: 80%;
}
.bl4 {
width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dflex1 bl1">
<label class="bl2">Введите номер вашего телефона</label>    
    <input class="bl3" type="text" placeholder="+7 ___-__-__">
    <select class="bl4"><option value=""><img src=".svg"></option><option value="2"><img src=".svg"></option> и тд.</select>
    </div>
```

Надеюсь вы уловили логику - а дальше просто стилизуйте все под свой вкус. И еще: img src=".svg" тут должны быть SVG изображения что бы быстрее грузилась форма.

Comment: спасибо большое тебе , а как внутри placeholder изменить ширину текста , а именно +7 --__--- вот это поле

Comment: используйте либо внутренний отступ например padding: 10px; или     line-height: 20px; @Тимур